# Complement of "dealer" or "trader"

Tags: antonyms, complements

What is the complement to a "dealer" or "trader" called?
Is the person who sells something to or buys something from the dealer a "customer"? Even when he sells something?

Comment: The person/firm that sells to the dealer can be referred to as  a "source" or "wholesaler" but they are not customers to the dealer.  Customers buy  ***from*** the dealer.  Sources (or wholesalers) sell ***to*** the dealer.

Comment: Also called *suppliers* or *OEMs* (Original Equipment Manufacturers) in some markets.

Comment: You say, ' The person who sells something or buys something to / from the dealer?'  That question seems to assume there will be one answer for both. There isn't.  You need two different words. Please ask a clearer question. Thanks.

Comment: After more generalizing I think "dealer" or "trader" could be called "contractor" so the other side would be a "client". Would that be correct?

Comment: Adding to my previous comment, I see that there is a word for both and Marv Mills has provided it.

Comment: It all depends on what is going on. Barter is commutative -- each trader gives something and gets something -- so there is not enough information to designate either partner by a special name. It's only when one of the commodities in a Barter Frame is identified as `Money` (thus creating a Commercial Transaction Frame) that the distinction between _buy_ and _sell_ emerges. The trader who receives `Money` is the seller, and the trader who gives `Money` is the buyer. Both are traders, or dealers; these refer to the Barter frame and are inherited by the Commercial Transaction Frame.

Comment: For more details about the Barter Frame and the Commercial Transaction Frame -- and the words associated with them -- see ["_Time Is Money_: The Anatomy of a Metaphor"](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/TIM.pdf) and ["Lexical Semantics in the Commercial Transaction Frame: _Value, worth, price,_ and _cost_"](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/valueworthpricecost.pdf).

Comment: Yes, I gave to less information. I´m looking for suitable words for a software architecture with includes two components I´m now naming contractor and client. The contractor offers to "buy" and "sell" information and the client asks for information (pull) or offers new information (push)

Comment: How about "trading partner"?  (Probably better than dealer<==>junkie.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term ["counterparty"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/counterparty?s=t) means:

> **noun**, *plural counterparties.* Finance.
>   1. the other person or institution entering into a financial contract or transaction
>
> *www.dictionary.com*

I don't think it is a *very* commonly used word outside of finance, but it is eminently suitable and can be applied irrespective of whether you are buying *from* or selling *to* that other party.

Comment: Counterparty *The other party that participates in a financial transaction. Every transaction must have a counterparty in order for the transaction to go through. More specifically, every buyer of an asset must be paired up with a seller that is willing to sell and vice versa.* Investopedia.com

Comment: It´s not exactly the word I´m looking for, but it´s a correct answer to my question. I decided to exchange the word "dealer" with "contractor", so the counterparty to this is the "client" :-)